# SSRS System.InvalidCastException - at OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that was pointed to `SQL Server views`, which pointed to `Oracle tables`.  I edited the SSRS report Dataset so as to query directly from the Oracle db.  It seems like a very simple change until I got this error message:

> **System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.**
>
> With the following details...
>
> `Field ‘UOM_QTY’` and it also says `at
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)`.

The SELECT statement on that field is pretty simple:

```
, (DELV_RECEIPT.INV_LBS/ITEM_UOM_XREF.CONV_TO_LBS) AS UOM_QTY
```

Does anyone know what would cause the message, and how to resolve the error?  My objective is use to use the ORACLE datasource instead of SQL SERVER.

---

**Error 1**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     [rsErrorReadingDataSetField] The dataset ‘dsIngredientCosts’ contains a definition for the Field ‘UOM_QTY’. The data extension returned an error during reading the field. System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.DataReaderWrapper.GetValue(Int32 fieldIndex)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.MappingDataReader.GetFieldValue(Int32 aliasIndex)      C:\Users\bl0040\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SSRS\Project_ssrs2016\Subscription Reports\Feed Ingredient Weekly Price Avg.rdl   0
```

**Error 2**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     [rsMissingFieldInDataSet] The dataset ‘dsIngredientCosts’ contains a definition for the Field ‘UOM_QTY’. This field is missing from the returned result set from the data source.       C:\Users\bl0040\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SSRS\Project_ssrs2016\Subscription Reports\Feed Ingredient Weekly Price Avg.rdl   0
```

---

Source Tables:

```
+------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| Source     | TABLE_NAME    | COLUMN_NAME | DataSize      | COLUMN_ID |
+------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| ORACLE     | DELV_RECEIPT  | INV_LBS     | NUMBER (7,0)  | 66        |
+------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| ORACLE     | ITEM_UOM_XREF | CONV_TO_LBS | NUMBER (9,4)  | 3         |
+------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| SQL SERVER | DELV_RECEIPT  | INV_LBS     | numeric (7,0) | 66        |
+------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| SQL SERVER | ITEM_UOM_XREF | CONV_TO_LBS | numeric (9,4) | 3         |
+------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: I oped up the RDL Code and tried modifying the `UOM_QTY Field` from 'System.Decimal' to 'System.Int32'-- `<rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>`.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: And I completely do not understand the Error 2 message `This field is missing from the returned result set from the data source.`, because the `UOM_QTY field` is certainly in the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error went away after adding a datatype conversion statement to the data selection.

```
   , CAST(DELV_RECEIPT.INV_LBS/ITEM_UOM_XREF.CONV_TO_LBS AS NUMERIC(9,4)) AS UOM_QTY
```

Can anyone provide some information on why the original query would be a problem and why the CAST would fix these errors?  I tried casting the results because someone on [Code Project forum](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/774153/How-Do-I-Solve-System-Invalidcastexception-Specifi) said...

> why don't you use typed datasets? you get such head aches just because
>   of not coding in a type-safe manner. you have a dataset designer in
>   the IDE which makes the life better, safer, easier and you don't use
>   it. I really can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to fix this error with an extension method instead of modifying the SQL-Query.

```
public static Decimal MyGetDecimal(this OracleDataReader reader, int i)
{
    try
    {
        return reader.GetDecimal(i);
    }
    catch (System.InvalidCastException)
    {
        Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal hlp = reader.GetOracleDecimal(i);
        Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal hlp2 = Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal.SetPrecision(hlp, 27);
        return hlp2.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to apply this extension method?  Is it some sort of property in the RDL file?

Comment: Are you familiar with extension methods?

Add a new 'public static class' to your project.

    public static class MyExtensionMethods()
    {
    }

Comment: RE: "Are you familiar with extension methods?".  No I am not.  What does an extension method do?  Is it C# related?  I'm not a C# programmer, but I'd be interested in learning about this option.  Could you provide a link to a video explaining extension methods.

Comment: Are you familiar with extension methods?  Extension-Methods extend other classes you don't have the source-code for, with new functions. In this case, OracleDataReader (only Oracle has the source-code for OracleDataReader) gets a new function with the name MyGetDecimal(int i)

Add a new 'public static class' to your project. eg: public static class MyExtensionFunctions. Add function MyGetDecimal to this new class.

  
And after that go to your source-code and replace each occurence of .GetDecimal  with .MyGetDecimal

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this but what happens if your query looks like:

SELECT x.* from x

and .GetDecimal appears nowhere?

Any suggestions in that case?  I have created a function in ORACLE itself that rounds all values in a result set to avoid this for basic select statements but this seems wrong for loading updateable datasets...
Obviously this is an old-school approach to getting data.